# Arcane archer's piercing arrow and sharphooter

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter

Can you take the sharphooter's -5 to hit, +10 damage ability and the piercing arrow arcane shot.  If so does it do the +10 on both a successful or failed save or only on a failed save?

Comment: Are you asking about the UA Arcane Archer or the XgtE Arcane Archer?

Comment: XgtE, didn't know there is more than 1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### You cannot use *Sharpshooter* with *Piercing Arrow*

*Sharpshooter* requires an attack roll, *Piercing Arrow* doesn't have one, it has a saving throw.

Comment: Where does it say it requires an attack roll?  Piercing Arrow counts as an attack with a ranged weapon that you are proficient in.  Aren't you adding to the text for sharpshooter "an attack that requires an attack roll".  You could argue this is implied but it is not stated.

Comment: @Dale See https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/936464530317570048?lang=en

Comment: @SteveBauer He did not add any text. The feat gives a "penalty to the attack roll". Also PA does *not* count as an attack, precisely because it does not involve an attack roll.

Comment: @DavidCoffron Ok, but you still cannot take a penalty to something that *does not exist*.

Comment: Clicking on the twitter link does not work for me.

Comment: @Szega Correct but the answer is not clear about why. I suggest block quoting with emphasis.

Comment: @Dale I agree you can't take the penalty but is there a principle because you can't take the penalty you don't get the benefit?

Comment: @Steve If you separate the sentences of the portion of the feat you would always get the benefit regardless of choosing the penalty. It probably could be improved with "if the attack still hits" but it has the same meaning.

Comment: @Szega The text for piercing arrow is you don't make an attack roll for this attack which I would take to say it does still count as an attack.  Maybe it should have been written to not count as an attack as it works more like an area effect spell ability than an attack but they specifically called it an attack.

Comment: It still counts as an attack. JC confirms. This works with things like Goblin's Fury of the Small, but not Sneak Attack or Sharpshooter for example.

Comment: Check out @JeremyECrawford’s Tweet: https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/941095016209850369?s=09

Comment: @DavidCoffron I disagree the second sentence already says "If the attack hits"  You could argue that Piercing Arrow does not hit but instead does damage as if it hit, I think that would be a valid argument.  But the argument that sharpshooter doesn't apply because there is no roll says the first sentence should really read "make an attack which has an attack roll."  Just because the feats penalty does not apply does not automatically mean you can't get the benefit, I would say that is the difference between a cost and a penalty.

Comment: I think this answer needs some explaining. If hundred-post long facebook arguments are any evidence, there is some unclarity in how the clauses of Sharpshooter and ***piercing arrow*** interact.